# Time doesnt appear in logs with pm2

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

Hello I would like the time t appear on my logs, i set the option on the dockerfile but time isn't displayed.

Dockerfile :

```
FROM ***

COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src

RUN npm install

ENV LD_PRELOAD /src/node_modules/sharp/vendor/lib/libz.so

RUN npm run build

RUN cp -rv /src/dist/* /src && rm -rf /src/dist

RUN mkdir -p /src/document && mkdir -p /src/tempUploads

ENV NODE_ENV __NODE_ENV__

RUN echo "Europe/Paris" > /etc/timezone && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

CMD ["pm2-docker", "index.js", "--log-date-format" "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--format` to get log in key=value format with timestamp like :

```
node-app_1 | timestamp=2017-10-30-12:04:25+0000 app=app id=0 type=out message=listening on *:3000
```

Or `--json` to get logs in JSON format also including timestamp like :

```
node-app_1 | {"message":"listening on *:3000","timestamp":"2017-10-30T12:06:10.615Z","type":"out","process_id":0,"app_name":"app"}
```

Comment: Ok but the logs are less visible like that, i like the actual display

Answer (score 0):

Set `--time`, or add `time: true` to your app config, for pm2 to prefix timestamps on all log messages.